# Gridview Bind Method Multiply

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to add into the gridview bind method multiplication?

I tried like this but it did not work: **'Bind("srp_amt") * 100'**

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("srp_amt") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll want to use a method to accomplish this. However, I want to make sure you understand that Bind is two way - in other words, you are both reading the data from, and writing data to, the database.

I'm guessing you may just want to perform a calculation for display only, but not end up writing that calculated result back to the database. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct Ethan I just want to multiply on the display.

Comment: If the user only needs to be able to see the value, and not edit it and or save it back to the database, then try <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# ((int)Eval("srp_amt") * 100) %>'></asp:Label>

Answer (score 1):

I think that is :

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# ((int)Bind("srp_amt") * 100) %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

your problem is that you need cast frist the value.

Comment: No, only the text that you get from database. If you need that after update you need do it by codebehind.

Comment: yes, you retain the original value, until you send the update database.